# What is this game with a wooden fish board and many little pinholes?

Tags: identify-this-game

I bought this in a thrift store in Sitka, Alaska, in 2014. I assume it's a 2-player game with little pins that go in the holes.

[image]

Does anyone know what game this might be?

Answer (score 16):

The fish is a plaice. The board layout looks similar to [Cribbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cribbage). There are different board layout to it, but wikipedia has one that looks like your fish. I'm saying similar since I'm unfamiliar with the game itself and there seems to be 4 little extra holes in your fish.

[image]

The Google search term I used was `peg 60 holes` and from there the first few images already returned similar ordered ones as on your fish.

As per the comment and credit to @Shannon, the extra holes are usually for either storing your pegs when not in use, or for keeping score for multiple games

Comment: The extra holes are usually for either storing your pegs when not in use, or for keeping score for multiple games (for cribbage, anyhow!).